# Can you console.log to the internal terminal in VScode when using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

However I try to do it, I can't get a console.log message to print out a message when I'm using react. If I create an empty document then it works, but if I try to console log something in a file where I've imported react nothing shows up. It instead gives me some errors that I don't even see to be there. Example:

```
const WeatherCard = (props) => {
let temp = 12
let topcolor = (1-((temp-12)/28))*255
let lowcolor = topcolor - 150

 return (
<div style={{backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(rgb(255,${topcolor},0),rgb(255, ${lowcolor},0))`}} className="card">
    <div className="location">
        <h1 className="city">Sydney</h1>
        <h3 className="country">AU</h3>
    </div>
    <img className="icon" src="./img/Mostly Cloudy-2x.png" alt="Weather Icon"/>
    <h1 className="temp">20°C</h1>
    <h3 className="conditon"> Clouds</h3>
</div>
    )
}

console.log("test")
export default WeatherCard
```

I then get:

````
file:///Users/MYCOMPUTER/Dropbox/Programmeringsprojekt/my-app/src/WeatherCard.js:10
<div style={{backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(rgb(255,${topcolor},0),rgb(255, ${lowcolor},0))`}} className="card">
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:141:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.086 seconds```
````

Comment: console.log usually used for printing into the browser console

Comment: AFAIK, the file should be **WeatherCard.jsx** not **WeatherCard.js** because that is not javascript, that's jsx

Comment: But can't you see the console.logs in the program in some way?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir i tried changing it but just got "language is not supported"

Comment: Please make sure you are importing React package in this Weather.js file

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir the file extension in vscode has more to do with what icon is displayed in the explorer and code highlighting, otherwise .js and .jsx are fairly interchangable, the transpiler handles the code. To Alexander, can you update your question to include a ***full*** code example snippet (if there is more). Can you also include the ***exact*** steps to reproduce the issue? As said, the console.log should be printing in the browser console, not in the vscode terminal window. It seems like you are trying to run your react function from the terminal or something odd like that.

Comment: It sounds like you need to configure VS Code to handle React code correctly. Most likely you need to install a plugin.

Comment: Try console logging inside the component, just above the return

Comment: @Code-Apprentice what plugin do you suggest?

Comment: Vscode itself has no bearing on how the code is being run, it's an editor. Again, I think you are trying to run your function directly (or something similar) and it likely won't work as it needs to be transpiled/built into vanilla javascript first.This is why I requested the *exact* steps you are doing to cause the issue.

Comment: @Alexander I don't use VS Code for React projects, so I can't provide a suggestion here. The error is clear that you aren't running your code correctly as Drew stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know 2 things before starting to code with React or JS:

**1) All code after a return statement won't be execute, so the console.log can't be read**

2. In react if you want to execute code before the component you have to use useEffect i let you read [this](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: The `console.log()` is global outside of any function. So the fact that it is after a return statement isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Console.log does work outside of the component.

Note that it will not print to the VSCode console, rather to the browser console.

As for the other error, you need to make sure you include the line `import React from 'react'`.

Comment: The *entire* file has javascript in it, you can console.log outside of react components.